# Jenkins can not export app-store ipa

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

The `ARCHIVE Process` is always successful,  but not the `EXPORT process`.

Here is the thing, when the export type is `development`, it always success.

But when I change the export type to `app-store`, it went wrong.

And here is the error message.

```
10:01:52 ** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **
10:01:52 
10:01:52 Cleaning up previously generated .ipa files
10:01:52 Cleaning up previously generated .dSYM.zip files
10:01:52 Packaging IPA
10:01:52 [XCodeProj] $ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :ApplicationProperties:CFBundleVersion" /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/artopia/artopia-iOS/XCodeProj/build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.xcarchive/Info.plist
10:01:52 [XCodeProj] $ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :ApplicationProperties:CFBundleShortVersionString" /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/artopia/artopia-iOS/XCodeProj/build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.xcarchive/Info.plist
10:01:52 Packaging Unity-iPhone.xcarchive => /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/artopia/artopia-iOS/artifacts/jenkins-Release-app-store-364.ipa
10:01:52 [XCodeProj] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/artopia/artopia-iOS/XCodeProj/build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.xcarchive -exportPath /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/artopia/artopia-iOS/artifacts -exportOptionsPlist /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/artopia/artopia-iOS/artifacts/app-store2477P575MMExport.plist
10:01:52 2018-01-09 10:01:52.598 xcodebuild[3570:174459] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/2w/320q_j1s5x10tmvq2rmwgx3c000086/T/Unity-iPhone_2018-01-09_10-01-52.597.xcdistributionlogs'.
10:01:53 2018-01-09 10:01:53.800 xcodebuild[3570:174459] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7f89ce77b200>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepErrorDomain Code=0 "Locating signing assets failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Locating signing assets failed., IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepUnderlyingErrors=(
10:01:53     "Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=1 \"No profiles for 'com.pantheon.artopia' were found\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No profiles for 'com.pantheon.artopia' were found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store provisioning profiles matching 'com.pantheon.artopia'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.}"
10:01:53 )}
10:01:53 error: exportArchive: No profiles for 'com.pantheon.artopia' were found
10:01:53 
10:01:53 Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=1 "No profiles for 'com.pantheon.artopia' were found" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No profiles for 'com.pantheon.artopia' were found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store provisioning profiles matching 'com.pantheon.artopia'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.}
10:01:53 
10:01:53 ** EXPORT FAILED **
```

The error message said that I don't have a proper provision profile for my app.

But I just make two app-store distribution profile for my app, one for `com.pantheon.artopia`, and one for wildcard.

And I actually download them and copy them to jenkins's provision profiles folder.

It also suggest to put `-allowProvisioningUpdates` to `xcodebuild`, and I actually did it.

But the bas thing is `-allowProvisioningUpdates` only passed to the `archive` step, but not to the `export` step.

So how could I solve this, I need your suggestions.

My jenkins settings are:[image][image][image]

Comment: I was having the same problem regarding provisioning profiles.Make sure you have placed you r profiles in the correct folders.Also check the name of the folders are correct.Mine were incorrect :)

Comment: Do you use jenkins? Why development is ok but not app-store, I saw profiles are all in one folder.

Comment: I used jenkins 3,4 months ago.I got the issue of profiles.Turns out my path was not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "General build settings" of the Xcode Plugin, just deselect step "Pack application, build and sign .ipa?", and add one "Execute Shell" step.

The shell script is simple:

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/artopia/artopia-iOS/XCodeProj/build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.xcarchive" -exportPath "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/artopia/artopia-iOS/artifacts" -exportOptionsPlist "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/artopia/artopia-iOS/exportoptions/ExportOptions-"${ExportType}".plist" -allowProvisioningUpdates
```

The only thing you should provide is `exportoptions.plist`, which you can find one in your own Xcode Export directory.

You can find more information in https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/9589